# In GitHub, How to See at a Glance Whether Multiple Repositories Have Differences Between Specified Branches?

Tags: git, github

I'm a Git/GitHub noob. Sorry.

I have several GitHub repositories. Each repository has a "master" branch for release version, and a "beta" branch for changes which I think are working but require testing.

New features are developed in additional branches, then I use pull requests to bring them into "beta" when the feature is finished.

When I use each application myself (this is my only testing, hah), I use the "beta" branch. Periodically, when I am satisfied there are no major bugs in "beta", I use another pull request to periodically bring "beta" into "master".

I think this is pretty basic usage.

But most of the time, for most of my repositories, "master" and "beta" are identical. And my testing/usage of "beta" can span some time, and sometimes I'll lose track of whether there are outstanding changes. I have to remind myself, periodically, to manually check each of my repositories, and start the create pull request process on each, just to check whether there are any differences between "master" and "beta" that need to be pulled into "master".

What I really need is some sort of single dashboard view that will let me see, at a glance, across multiple repositories, which ones have differences between their "master" and "beta" branches.

The best solution I've identified, so far, is to reinforce a habit, every time I merge a feature into "beta", to check and ensure there is an open PR from "beta" into "master", and if not, create the PR, and leave it open. Then https://github.com/pulls will show all of those in one page. But if I fail this habit behavior, it can get lost again.

Is there a better way?

Comment: After looking into it further, basically I want to consolidate a bunch of these pages onto a single dashboard: https://github.com/USER/REPOSITORY/compare/master...beta I tried making my own local .HTML file as dashboard with iframes but these sites deny cross domain loading in iframes, I think. Is there an easy way to bypass this for a local HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not great, but the only easy answer I could come up with: In my web browser (Chrome), I made a Folder of Bookmarks, and added a Bookmark for each Repository, specifically at URL: https://github.com/USER/REPO/compare/master...beta

I then train a behavior to always use those bookmarks as my entry point to GitHub, and am therefore regularly reminded if there is any outstanding difference between the branches.

I can also right-click on the whole Folder and click "Open all bookmarks" to get a quick in-my-face review across my suite.